# Passing double calculations returned inside different methods?

Tags: android, variables, methods, android-activity, void

My program right now does the following:

- User enters a value
- User picks a conversion
- User hits submit

Based on the conversion picked (Using radio buttons) I need to call a method that will perform the calculations of the conversion which will then return the conversion to the case but I am having issues with it since I am returning a double.

```
package com.exercise_5;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private String textValue;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}

// Method called when the convert button is clicked
public void convert(View view) {
    RadioGroup conRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.conRadioGroup);
    EditText textValue = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    switch(conRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()) {
    case R.id.radioCelsiusToFahrenheit:
// Call the convert method
        fahrenheitToCelsius();
//Return the converted variable

        break;

    case R.id.radioFahrenheitToCelsius:
        fahrenheitToCelsius();

        break;

    default:
       Log.e("Some class tag", "Invalid id was passed to conversion method doing celsius conversion.");
       return celsiusToFahrenheit();
       break; 
     }

}

public void fahrenheitToCelsius(Convert tempCelsius) { 

    double conCelsius = Double.parseDouble(textValue);

    //Calculate Celsius
    tempCelsius = ((conCelsius * 9) / 5) + 32; 
}

public double celsiusToFahrenheit(double tempInFahrenheit) {

    double conFahrenheit = Double.parseDouble(textValue);

    //Calculate Fahrenheit
    return ((conFahrenheit * 9) / 5) + 32;
}

public void clear(View view) {
    //Reset Appended Strings After Previous Run
    TextView fahrenheit_TV = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    TextView celsius_TV = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textView3);

    fahrenheit_TV.setText("Fahrenheit: ");
    celsius_TV.setText("Celsius: ");

}
```

}

Comment: Can you tell exactly what you want ?

Comment: Basically what I need is for my fahrenheit method to be called when the case is initiated and then the fahrenheit method should return a double that I can use to append a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Kuu, actually no.  If either of the variables in a binary operation (addition, multiplication, subtraction, addition, remainder) are doubles then Java treats both values as doubles, so the result in the

((conCelsius * 9) / 5) + 32

operation is a double.

To answer the actual questions, there are several problems with the code. The correct way to setup related radio buttons is to group them in radio button group (I assume you are not given the code). For an example see  http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-radio-buttons-example/

After doing that you can check which buttons was selected by the id of the radio button.

This the general layout for the code:

```
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    radioTempConvGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioTempConvGroup);
    btnConvert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnConvert);

    btnConvert.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                // get selected radio button from radioGroup
            int selectedId = radioTempConvGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

                    double convertedTemp = convert(selectedId);
                    //do other operations with convertedTemp like display 
        }

    });


  private double convertTemp(int selectedId) {
       //TODO get value from the textview that holds  the value
       double temperature = //INSERT code to get the value to convert
       switch(selectedId) {
       case  R.id.radioCelsius:
           return celsiusToFahrenheit(temperature);
           break;
       case R.id.radioFahrenheit:
           return fahrenheitTocelsius(temperature);
          break;
       default:
          Log.e("Some class tag", "Invalid id was passed to conversion method doing celsius conversion.");
          return celsiusToFahrenheit(temperature);
          break; 
        }
   }

   private double celsiusToFahrenheit(double tempInCelsius) {
      //TODO add actual conversion
   }

   private double fahrenheitToCelsius(double tempInFahrenheit) {
      //TODO add actual conversion
   }
```

There are several issues with your code:

Always use braces with if and similar constructs in order to prevent executing one instructions instead of several. I assume

```
case R.id.radioButton1:
    if (checked)
        fahrenheit();

        //Append Strings
        fahrenheit_TV.append(" " +fahrenheit.conversion);

    break;
```

was intended as

```
case R.id.radioButton1:
    if (checked) {
        fahrenheit();

        //Append Strings
        fahrenheit_TV.append(" " +fahrenheit.conversion);
    }
    break;
```

however only the instruction immediately after the if is executed in your version.

Don't use Double when the primitive double will suffice.  Object creation and boxing and unboxing are expensive operations.

```
  public static double fahrenheit(Double conversion) {

    Double conCelsius = Double.parseDouble(getCelsius);

    //Calculate Celsius
    return ((conCelsius * 9) / 5) + 32;
  }
```

should be:

```
  public static double fahrenheit(double conversion) {

    double conCelsius = Double.parseDouble(getCelsius);

    //Calculate Celsius
    return ((conCelsius * 9) / 5) + 32;
  }
```

Thirdly, try to be consistent throughout the code and/or try to use the java conventions, it makes easier for other people (and you after 6 months) to read the code.
One method names starts with  upper case, another  with lower case letters. Some variables
use _ for separations, other use camel case.

Comment: Thank you very much for cleaning up my code, I am starting from scratch and this was much appreciated.

Comment: I am having a problem returning the calculations and calling the switch statement, care to expand on how to properly do this?

Comment: What exactly is the problem ?

Comment: Well I ditched the onClickListener idea because its not worth changing so much code so far into my app but I need to call my convert methods in the switch and then grab the variable in the convert method. I edited the original post with my new code.

Comment: What do you mean? I am just very confused about why I cannot even call my calculations in my switch statement.

Comment: To me it seems that you do not seem to understand how passing and returning values from methods works.

see http://blog.sanaulla.info/2008/07/02/passing-variables-into-methods-java-passing-mechanism-explained/


Also, I updated the code I posted in the switch statement to something similar to what you should have.

You need a pass a value in the fahrenheitToCelsius  method and return the converted value. 

I had an editing mishap earlier, that is the reason  for the strange answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem that you get is because your operations are done with integer numbers (multiplying by 9 and dividing by 5) and therefore the compiler is transforming conCelsius to int while making the calculus, instead it should be like this:

```
return ((conCelsius * 9.0) / 5.0) + 32;
```